# Advanced Custom Fields for Header that are Editable from a Page

Tags: custom-field, headers

I am trying to make a phone numbers section, using advanced custom fields in my header. Currently with my source code below the phone numbers only show on the header when the home page is displayed. This is because I have the fields editable in the home page content editor. I need them to be editable in the CMS but I also need them to be global in the header.

Source code example as follows (also using a click to call link):

```
    <h3>Live In Care: <a href="tel:<?php the_field('live_in_ctc'); ?>"><?php the_field('live_in'); ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: What do you mean editiable?  In the frontend where they are displayed? or in the backend?  Are you sure you didn't put that code in an is_home statement?

Comment: Search ACF plugin documentation for the_field and you will find examples of how to pass a page ID to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with a theme supporting the WP customizer: Using the customizer.php file (can be found in sub-folder 'inc', or perform a search, varies from theme to theme. Make you own = [Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/))

So, in your customizer.php - Add this:

```
// Add to customizer.php inside function your_customizer($wp_customize) {}
$wp_customize->add_setting(
'live_in_ctc',
 array(
 'default'           => '',
 'type'              => 'theme_mod',
 'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
 'transport'         => 'postMessage',
 'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw'
 )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
'live_in_ctc',
 array(
 'label'             => 'Live In Tel',
 'section'           => 'title_tagline', // Site Identity section
 'type'              => 'url',
 'priority'          => '15'
 )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
'live_in_label',
 array(
 'default'           => '',
 'type'              => 'theme_mod',
 'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
 'transport'         => 'postMessage',
 'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr'
 )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
'live_in_label',
 array(
 'label'             => 'Live In Label',
 'section'           => 'title_tagline', // Site Identity section
 'type'              => 'text',
 'priority'          => '16'
 )
);
```

Now, look for customizer.js. Typically found in the same folder as customizer.php (file names will vary from theme-to-theme. Look for the word "customizer").

Add this to customizer.js within the function($):

```
wp.customize('live_in_label', function(value) {
 value.bind(function(to) {
  $('.classname a').text(to); // wrap your h3 in a div with .classname
 });
});
```

Change:

```
<h3>Live In Care: <a href="tel:<?php the_field('live_in_ctc'); ?>"><?php the_field('live_in_label'); ?></a></h3>
```

To:

```
<div class="classname"><h3>Live In Care:&nbsp;<a href="tel:<?php echo get_theme_mod('live_in_ctc'); ?>" title="telephone number"><?php echo get_theme_mod('live_in_label'); ?></a></h3></div>
```

To allow the telephone number/label to appear throughout your site, try adding the 'To:' update to your header.php, at the very bottom. Comment out the original first. Test and see what happens. I'll bet additional css will be needed to get the number to render just right.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a plan - I am not using a theme, coding up in bootstrap and converting to an underscore starter template.

Comment: I have a few numbers to add - would I reference them all in one customizer function, or do the full code for each one?

Comment: I use the _s theme as well.. So, adding additional numbers is as easy as creating new setting and control and then adding new wp.customize to to customizer.js. get_theme_mod is how to display input from customizer. Review the customizer API.

Comment: Your customizer.php is in the 'inc' folder and customizer.js is in the js folder = theme directory